# Removing single anonymous child node in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am building a simple 2D game. It basically consist of a player moving around in a maze. I store the blueprint of the field as ASCII characters in an array, and translate those into images projected on a CSS grid.

One of the components is a wall, for which I stored the image tag in `wall` and the grid element that's holding it in `element` (the ASCII character in the array for wall is  `X`):

`case 'X': element.appendChild(wall.cloneNode()); break;`

Since apparently you cannot use the same node twice, I had to use `cloneNode()`.

At some point I need to remove a piece of wall. I want to use `element.removeChild()`, but how do I reference the node? It appears to have no name, but using `element.removeChild()` or `element.removeChild('')` as well as many different things I tried out don't work.

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: You should keep track of your nodes in an array or an object.

Comment: `element.firstElementChild.remove()`.

Comment: That's it! Thanks!